# Cross Tabulation with R Markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, markdown, crosstab

I have struggle creating a simple nice looking cross tabulation for a **PDF knitted R Markdown** document. I have a data set that is similar to this example:

```
library(tidyverse)
fakeData <- tibble(id = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
                   bmi = c("normal", "overweighted", "underweighted", "normal", "normal", "overweighted",
                           "normal", "overweighted", "underweighted","normal"),
                   gender = c("M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "F", "M", "F", "F", "F"))
```

I want to get an output like this one:

[image: Desired output]

Have anyone a trick/ a known good package to do this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you tried `knitr::kable()`?

Comment: In my mind kable() is more about printing a dataframe or matrix in a table form. But here I want to get the stats number and frequency in addition. It's more like what you see in scientific journals, for example study population characterization tables.

Comment: I understand your question now; I thought it was about table formatting, but you also want the calculations

Comment: Yep, I mean I can do the calculations with code but I'm looking for a more elegant and reproducible way to do it since I have a bunch of data.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the `janitor`-package can help you out here...

note: the percentages in the 'total' column do not match your desired output... That is because you are mixing colwise and rowwise percentage calculation in your output.. Is that really what you want?

```
library( janitor )

fakeTable <- fakeData %>% 
  tabyl( gender, bmi ) %>% 
  adorn_totals( where = c("row", "col") ) %>%
  adorn_percentages("row") %>%
  adorn_pct_formatting() %>%
  adorn_ns( position = "front" ) %>%
  adorn_title("combined")

# gender/bmi    normal overweighted underweighted       Total
#          F 2 (33.3%)    3 (50.0%)     1 (16.7%)  6 (100.0%)
#          M 3 (75.0%)    0  (0.0%)     1 (25.0%)  4 (100.0%)
#      Total 5 (50.0%)    3 (30.0%)     2 (20.0%) 10 (100.0%)
```

**knitted**

```
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
fakeTable %>%
  kable() %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("condensed", "striped", "bordered"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That looks great I'll try this option. And sorry for the confusing fake table, I messed the percentages, I was distracted I guess.... :)

Comment: And may I also ask if you know a good alternative if I want a table that is similar but with age mean and SD for example instead of frequency?

Answer (score 2):

I think the package `summarytools` can produce the desired output.
Using your fakeData:

```
library(summarytools)
print(ctable(x = fakeData$gender, y = fakeData$bmi, prop = "t"),
      method = "render")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, thats a great tip.