# How to create table in R and get output n pdf or word?

Tags: r, pivot-table

I want to create a table which can be exported to pdf or word document. Is there any package can be used to get the table automatically/quickly? I tried pivottabler and table1 package and i do got the output but the format is not exactly what i required.

Data: Lets consider mtcars data.

```
    cars             mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant             18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
Duster 360          14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
Merc 240D           24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
Merc 230            22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
Merc 280            19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
Merc 280C           17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
Merc 450SE          16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
Merc 450SL          17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
Merc 450SLC         15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
```

Output: I want to create the above data in the table as per below example

```
Vs *disp*  mpg     am_1      am_0       *Total*
0 460      21.0   20 (11%)    0         20 (11%)
  120      21.0   8 (9%)      8 (9%)    16 (18%)
  151      18.7   2 (2%)      3(1%)     5 (3%)

1 151      12.0   8 (9%)      9 (10%)   17(19%)
  424      25.0   118 (10%)   6 (5%)    124 (15%)
```

The above values are not correct. Its just an example. I want a table in the above format.

When i try using pivottabler package,

```
pt <- PivotTable$new()
pt$addData(mtcars)
pt$addColumnDataGroups("am")
pt$addRowDataGroups("vs")
pt$addRowDataGroups("mpg", totalCaption= "Subtotal") 
pt$addRowDataGroups("disp", addTotal=FALSE) #    << **** CODE CHANGE **** <<
pt$defineCalculation(calculationName="Total", summariseExpression="n()")
pt$renderPivot()
```

I got the below output, but i want the values to be in count and percentage in same cell

[image: Output]

Comment: take a look at the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62116246/cross-tabulation-with-r-markdown/62116721#62116721

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest two options for what you want. First you need to do the processing of data:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
library(officer)
#Data
data("mtcars")
#Format
S <- mtcars %>% group_by(vs,cyl,am) %>% summarise(N=n()) %>% ungroup() %>%
  group_by(vs,cyl) %>% mutate(Total=sum(N),Percentage=100*round(N/Total,3)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = am,values_from = c(N,Percentage)) %>%
  replace(is.na(.), 0) %>%
  mutate(N_1=paste0(N_1,' (',paste0(Percentage_1,'%'),')'),
         N_0=paste0(N_0,' (',paste0(Percentage_0,'%'),')'),
         Total=paste0(Total,'(',paste0(Percentage_1+Percentage_0,'%'),')')) %>%
  select(vs,cyl,N_0,N_1,Total)
```

You will get this (You can adapt to what you want, this is an example):

```
# A tibble: 5 x 5
# Groups:   vs, cyl [5]
     vs   cyl N_0        N_1       Total   
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>      <chr>     <chr>   
1     0     4 0 (0%)     1 (100%)  1(100%) 
2     0     6 0 (0%)     3 (100%)  3(100%) 
3     0     8 12 (85.7%) 2 (14.3%) 14(100%)
4     1     4 3 (30%)    7 (70%)   10(100%)
5     1     6 4 (100%)   0 (0%)    4(100%)
```

Now the first option is exporting to pdf using `grid` and `gridExtra` packages:

```
#Prepare for export option 1 using grid
myTable <- tableGrob(
  S, 
  rows = NULL, 
  theme = ttheme_default(core = list(bg_params = list(fill = "grey99")))
)
#Export to pdf
pdf('Example.pdf',width = 10)
grid.draw(myTable)
dev.off()
```

You will obtain a `.pdf` with an image like this:

[image]

Second option is `officer` package:

```
#Second option with officer package
doc <- read_docx() %>%
  body_add_par(value = "My Table", style = "heading 1") %>%
  body_add_table(value = S, style = "Table Professional",alignment = "c" )
print(doc, target = "Example.docx")
```

You will end up with a `.docx` document like this:

[image]

Comment: i am not getting the required output

Comment: Is it possible to get the output using the pivottabler or table1 package itself @cbailiss

Comment: When i try running your code, i get error. `summarise()` regrouping output by 'vs', 'cyl' (override with `.groups` argument)

Comment: @Learner That is just a warning ! Please check if `S` was created!

Comment: ya i got it ...Thank you.. but i still facing anther problem. Is there any way to contact you personally?

Comment: @Learner I have seen you can open a chat and invite me so that I could help you with any issue. If you make that I can help you. Also if you believe this answer was helpful you could accept it. It is up to you :)

Comment: @Learner First please check this link on how to create chats https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187426/how-do-i-chat-with-another-user-on-stackoverflow Let me know if you were able to create it!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219993/discussion-between-learner-and-duck).

Comment: Thanks alot..i got the output....i really appreciate your time :)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest knitting the table in an r markdown file using `knitr::kable` as in:

```
library(knitr)
library(tidyverse)
kable(mtcars %>% dplyr::select(am, vs, mpg, disp)... )
```

You can hide code that generates the table in the output PDF with the heading `{r cars,echo=FALSE}`. You can do all the standard data manipulations to your data within the first kable argument, or do them in the r markdown setup and feed kable your final dataframe as argument x.
In an r markdown file, you can knit the document to either PDF of Word format under the 'knit' tab in r studio. Is this what you had in mind?

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two ways to approach this with the pivottabler package.

Both approaches define multiple calculations:

- The first calculation is the basic count
- The second calculation overrides the filters present in each cell, so that only the filter from the column variable(s) apply to the cell - which means this calculation always gives the column total.  This calculation is not visible in the pivot table (visible=FALSE has been specified).
- The third calculation either calculates the percentage of column total (approach 1) or calculates a concatenated value of the count and the percentage of column total (approach 2).

**Approach 1**

This uses two separate columns which (IMHO) is easier to read:

```
library(pivottabler)

pt <- PivotTable$new()
pt$addData(mtcars)
pt$addColumnDataGroups("am")
pt$addRowDataGroups("vs")
pt$addRowDataGroups("mpg", totalCaption= "Subtotal") 
pt$addRowDataGroups("disp", addTotal=FALSE)

# basic calculation
pt$defineCalculation(calculationName="CountVal", caption="V", summariseExpression="n()")

# get column totals
filterOverrides <- PivotFilterOverrides$new(pt, keepOnlyFiltersFor="am")
pt$defineCalculation(calculationName="CountAll", summariseExpression="n()", filters=filterOverrides, visible=FALSE)

# percentage of column calculation total
pt$defineCalculation(calculationName="Percent", caption="%",
                     type="calculation", basedOn=c("CountVal", "CountAll"),
                     format="%.1f %%",
                     calculationExpression="values$CountVal/values$CountAll*100")

pt$renderPivot()
```

[image: Approach 1]

**Approach 2**

This combines the values into one column:

```
library(pivottabler)

pt <- PivotTable$new()
pt$addData(mtcars)
pt$addColumnDataGroups("am")
pt$addRowDataGroups("vs")
pt$addRowDataGroups("mpg", totalCaption= "Subtotal") 
pt$addRowDataGroups("disp", addTotal=FALSE)

# basic calculation
pt$defineCalculation(calculationName="CountVal", summariseExpression="n()", visible=FALSE)

# get column totals
filterOverrides <- PivotFilterOverrides$new(pt, keepOnlyFiltersFor="am")
pt$defineCalculation(calculationName="CountAll", summariseExpression="n()", filters=filterOverrides, visible=FALSE)

# percentage of column calculation total
pt$defineCalculation(calculationName="Percent", caption="Percent",
                     type="calculation", basedOn=c("CountVal", "CountAll"),
                     calculationExpression="paste0(values$CountVal, ' (', sprintf('%.1f %%', values$CountVal/values$CountAll*100), ')')")

pt$renderPivot()
```

[image: Approach 2]

**Approach 2 - update 1**

The following version of approach 2 displays headings for the row groups and changes the calculation values so that zero is displayed without brackets.

```
library(pivottabler)

pt <- PivotTable$new()
pt$addData(mtcars)
pt$addColumnDataGroups("am")
pt$addRowDataGroups("vs", header="vs")
pt$addRowDataGroups("mpg", totalCaption= "Subtotal", header="mpg") 
pt$addRowDataGroups("disp", addTotal=FALSE, header="disp")

# basic calculation
pt$defineCalculation(calculationName="CountVal", summariseExpression="n()", visible=FALSE)

# get column totals
filterOverrides <- PivotFilterOverrides$new(pt, keepOnlyFiltersFor="am")
pt$defineCalculation(calculationName="CountAll", summariseExpression="n()", filters=filterOverrides, visible=FALSE)

# percentage of column calculation total
pt$defineCalculation(calculationName="Percent", caption="Percent",
                     type="calculation", basedOn=c("CountVal", "CountAll"),
                     calculationExpression="ifelse(is.null(values$CountVal)||values$CountVal==0, 0, paste0(values$CountVal, ' (', sprintf('%.1f %%', values$CountVal/values$CountAll*100), ')'))")

pt$renderPivot(showRowGroupHeaders=TRUE)
```

[image: Approach 2 - update 1]

**Approach 2 - update 2**

This change moves the subtotals to the top, removes the grand total at the bottom, shows the percentage with no decimal places.

```
library(pivottabler)

pt <- PivotTable$new()
pt$addData(mtcars)
pt$addColumnDataGroups("am")
pt$addRowDataGroups("vs", header="vs", addTotal=FALSE)
pt$addRowDataGroups("mpg", totalCaption= "Subtotal", header="mpg", totalPosition="before") 
pt$addRowDataGroups("disp", addTotal=FALSE, header="disp")

# basic calculation
pt$defineCalculation(calculationName="CountVal", summariseExpression="n()", visible=FALSE)

# get column totals
filterOverrides <- PivotFilterOverrides$new(pt, keepOnlyFiltersFor="am")
pt$defineCalculation(calculationName="CountAll", summariseExpression="n()", filters=filterOverrides, visible=FALSE)

# percentage of column calculation total
pt$defineCalculation(calculationName="Percent", caption="Percent",
                     type="calculation", basedOn=c("CountVal", "CountAll"),
                     calculationExpression="ifelse(is.null(values$CountVal)||values$CountVal==0, 0, paste0(values$CountVal, ' (', sprintf('%.0f %%', values$CountVal/values$CountAll*100), ')'))")

pt$renderPivot(showRowGroupHeaders=TRUE)
```

[image: Approach 2 - update 2]

Comment: thank you, i was able to get the output...Is there any way to get the variable names also for Vs *disp*  mpg variables? Also, i want the blanks to be filled with 0 (0.0 %) in this format..i tried adding noDataCaption='0' then also i am not getting the correct format

Comment: sorry only 0 not 0 (0.0 %)

Comment: I have updated the answer to include an updated version of approach 2 which displays row group headings and changes the way blank/zero is displayed.  See above.

Comment: Requests 1, 2, and 4 have been incorporated into Approach 2 - update 2 in the answer above.  Request 3 - depends on where you are viewing the pivot table.  If you are viewing in the "Viewer" pane in R-Studio, try making the pane wider or clicking on the  "Show in new window" button.

Comment: This question is turning into a longer thread of different questions - please see the extensive documentation as well to help you learn: http://pivottabler.org.uk/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220025/discussion-between-learner-and-cbailiss).

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link. i have seen the link and then created the basic table...but the formatting part, i was not able to do or find in the document...